# Convert file path into object

Tags: javascript, json

Say I have the following strings:

> "files/photos/foo.png"

> "files/videos/movie.mov"

and I want to convert them to the following object:

```
{
    name: "files"
    children: [{
        name: "photos",
        children: [{
            name: "foo.png",
            id: "files/photos/foo.png"
        }]
    },{
        name: "videos",
        children: [{
            name: "movie.mov",
            id: "files/videos/movie.mov"
        }]
    }]
}
```

What would be the best approach for doing so?  I've tried writing some recursive functions, however admit that I'm struggling at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, first was C#, see: [Javascript: How to create an object from a dot separated string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464393/javascript-how-to-create-an-object-from-a-dot-separated-string). While the final shape of the objects in the duplicate is different the method is applicable. Also, [tree from array of dot-separated strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62490323/tree-from-array-of-dot-separated-strings)

Comment: @pilchard thanks for the references, those are close to what I'm looking for.  Unfortunately I need to be able to combine multiple strings into one object, which doesn't look possible with those solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick snippet with a possible solution. It uses nested loops, the outer splitting each path by the delimeter and `pop()`ing the file portion out of the array. The inner iterates the parts of the path and constructs the heirarchy by reasigning `branch` on each iteration. Finally the `file` portion of the path is added to the deepest `branch`.

```js
const data = [
  'files/photos/foo.png',
  'files/photos/bar.png',
  'files/videos/movie.mov',
  'docs/photos/sd.jpg'
];

const tree = { root: {} }
for (const path of data) {

  const parts = path.split('/');
  const file = parts.pop();

  let branch = tree, partPath = '';
  for (const part of parts) {
    partPath += `${part}/`;

    if (partPath === `${part}/`) {
      tree.root[partPath] = (tree[partPath] ??= { name: part, children: [] });
    } else if (tree[partPath] === undefined) {
        tree[partPath] = { name: part, children: [] };
        branch.children.push(tree[partPath]);
    }

    branch = tree[partPath];
  }

  branch.children.push({ name: file, id: path });
}

const result = Object.values(tree.root)

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
.as-console-row::after { display: none !important; }
```

Or as a function.

```js
function mergeAssets(assets) {
  const tree = { root: {} }

  for (const path of data) {
    const parts = path.split('/');
    const file = parts.pop();

    let branch = tree, partPath = '';
    for (const part of parts) {
      partPath += `${part}/`;

      if (partPath === `${part}/`) {
        tree.root[partPath] = (tree[partPath] ??= { name: part, children: [] });
      } else if (tree[partPath] === undefined) {
        tree[partPath] = { name: part, children: [] };
        branch.children.push(tree[partPath]);
      }

      branch = tree[partPath];
    }

    branch.children.push({ name: file, id: path });
  }

  return {
    name: "assets",
    children: Object.values(tree.root)
  }
}

const data = [
  'files/photos/foo.png',
  'files/photos/bar.png',
  'files/videos/movie.mov',
  'docs/photos/sd.jpg'
];

const result = mergeAssets(data);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution using a recursive function.  If others have any tips on how to improve this, I'd love to hear.

```
function mergeObjects(parentArray,path,originalName){
    if(originalName === undefined){
        originalName = path;
    }

    const parts = path.split("/");
    var nextPart = "";
    parts.forEach((part, index) => index > 0 ? nextPart += (nextPart !== "" ? "/" : "") + part : null);
    //does the parentArray contain a child with our name?
    const indexOfChild = parentArray.findIndex(child => child.name === parts[0]);
    if(indexOfChild === -1){
        //this item does not exist
        if(parts.length > 1){
            var index = parentArray.push({
                name: parts[0],
                children : []
            }) - 1;
            mergeObjects(parentArray[index].children,nextPart,originalName);
        }else{
            parentArray.push({
                name: parts[0],
                id : originalName
            });
        }
    }else{
        //this item already exists
        if(parts.length > 1){
            mergeObjects(parentArray[indexOfChild].children,nextPart,originalName);
        }
    }
}
```

And the function is called with the following:

```
function mergeAssets(assets){
    var obj = {
        name: "assets",
        children: []
    };
    assets.forEach(asset => mergeObjects(obj.children,asset));
    return obj;
}
```